# How get all assemblies referenced in a project from an assembly referenced by that project?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-4.0

I want to make a library that can find all classes in a runtime that fit some criteria (e.g. have an attribute). I need it to be able to find those classes even if they're in other libraries brought in to the project. For example:

```
Project
|_______> Library "A"
|_______> Library "B"
```

I want "A" to be able to find a class that's in "B".

When I tried the following, none of the "B" classes show up:

```cs
typeof(CurrentClassInA).Assembly.GetExportedTypes();
```

How can I get all (public) types of the project *and* any inside the libraries it uses/references/loads?

Comment: You should be able to get the project's executable assembly with `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`. From there, you can get andenumerate the assemblies referenced by the project assembly by using projectEntryAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()`, in which you then again search for the type(s) you are after. (to keep things speedy, you might also want to filter out any referenced assembly that's not a .NET Core assembly or not otherwise located in the "correct" directory, or so...)

Comment: @elgonzo How would I determine an assembly is not in a "correct" directory?

Comment: By checking the `Location` property of an assembly.

Comment: @elgonzo I meant, what sort of value in that location property would be knowable as incorrect?

Comment: That's up to you to decide, hence why i did put "correct" into quote marks. I don't know whether your project references assemblies residing in locations other than the directory of the program executable (for example like assemblies from the GAC or package runtime store) or not. If you already know the directory the assembly with the class you are looking for is in, then (when enumerating the referenced assemblies) you can filter out any assembly that might happen to be _not_ in this directory...